# HTTP Status 404 when packaging WAR in EAR file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, war, ear

I'm using JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final and have been having problems getting my deployment to work.  I have a couple of EJB jar files and a WAR file that I'm packaging into a single EAR.  If I deploy the WAR file separately, I'm able to access it by the context-root specified in the jboss-web.xml file. However, when I package it up into an EAR file, I keep getting a "HTTP Status 404 - /pacbridge-web/" error for the same URL.

Here is what I have

```
EAR File:
|---pacbridge-app-6.0.0.jar
|---pacbridge-dom-6.0.0.jar
|---pacbridge-ejb-6.0.0.jar
|---pacbridge-web-6.0.0.war
|---META-INF
    |---application.xml
    |---MANIFEST.MF
|---lib
    |----bunch of jar files
```

My application.xml looks like this:

```
<application ...>
  <display-name>pacbridge-ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>pacbridge-web-6.0.0.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/pacbridge-web</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>pacbridge-ejb-6.0.0.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>pacbridge-app-6.0.0.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>pacbridge-dom-6.0.0.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

I'm not sure that it's applicable but there is my jboss-web.xml file:

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>pacbridge-web</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Could someone give me some hints as to what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are there any logs generated that we could look at?

Comment: try taking out the leading '/' in your application.xml file `context-root`, also try removing your jboss-web.xml file as that file only makes sense when deploying a WAR outside of an EAR

Comment: I don't know if posting the log would be helpful. It's pretty big. There are no errors only a single warning about hibernate.search.lucene_version--unrelated.  The only log message that looks remotely interesting is this: "08:37:20,644 INFO [org.jboss.web]  JBAS018210: Registering web context: /pacbridge-web", which, I assume, means the war was deployed.  Is there anything in particular I should be looking for?

Comment: Shadow: I tried removing the jboss-web.xml file but that made no difference.